# Coffeescript (jQuery) in Rails app doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I am struggling with implementing a functionality with jQuery + Coffeescript - the problem is that the code doesn't show any `alert` windows.

Here's the JS functionality:

```
jQuery ->
  Stripe.setPublishableKey($('meta[name="stripe-key"]').attr('content'))
  subscription.setupForm()

subscription =
  setupForm: ->
    $('#new_subscription').submit ->
      $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', true)
      if $('#card_number').length
        subscription.processCard()
        false
      else
        true

  processCard: ->
    card =
      number: $('#card_number').val()
      cvc: $('#card_code').val()
      expMonth: $('#card_month').val()
      expYear: $('#card_year').val()
    Stripe.createToken(card, subscription.handleStripeResponse)

  handleStripeResponse: (status, response) ->
    if status == 200
      $('#subscription_stripe_card_token').val(response.id)
      $('#new_subscription')[0].submit()
    else
      $('#stripe_error').text(response.error.message)
      $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', false)
```

All `class`and `id` attributes are configured properly, but when I click the button, no `alert` window is called.

When I put an `alert` window before the `jQuery ->` line,

```
alert('asf')
jQuery ->
...
```

the `alert window` is displayed, but when I do

```
jQuery ->
alert('asf')
...
```

then is not displayed.

The file above is successfully loaded. I am using jQuery `v1.11.1`, Rails `v4`.

What am I overlooking here?

Thank oyu

Comment: Yes, I am using TurboLinks in the app.

Answer (score 0):

Intendation is important in coffescript

```
jQuery ->
  alert('asf')
```

will produce

```
 jQuery(function() {
   return alert('asf');
 });
```

However

```
jQuery ->
alert('asf')
```

Will produce

```
jQuery(function() {});
alert('asf');
```

Perhaps screwed up some other intendations. Check the compiled js code with chrome dev tools of Firebug or the like